# ReactJs component showing old data (which is not a list even)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Post = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  const [post, setPost] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPost();
  }, []);

  const fetchPost = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.example/v1/json/post?post=${params.postSlug}`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setPost(response.data.data.post);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log({ error }));
  };

  return post ? (
    <div className="singlePost">
      <div className="content" key="content">{post.content}</div>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

export default Post;
```

This is my whole component and API is developed on laravel. If I change the backend data from db React client does not pull in the new content while if I paste the endpoint in a browser or Postman, it does display updated content. I know that I can just add a timestamp at the end of url to force frontend to pull new data everytime but that'll effect the efficiency of application. Can someone explain the reason and solution to this issue without using any cache burst (i.e. timestamp in url or 'no-cache' in axios headers).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're wanting the frontend to detect that you've made changes to your database?

Comment: @BrianThompson, No as I mentioned in the question, If I paste the endpoint in a browser or Postman, it does display updated content. but on the application side at page refresh, it displays old data

Comment: Could you try to add params or postSlug as a dependency in the useEffect Hook? See answer below.

Comment: It looks like there is nothing wrong here. Is this the actual code your using/running or is this just a "summarized" version? It's very common for people to post a short version of their code on SO..

Comment: You could disable caching and use a library like [react query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) to do the fetching and caching for you.

Comment: does your problem has been solved?

Comment: If you look at the headers that Postman is adding to requests, you'll see it's adding no-cache to the request: https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/settings/#headers.  So, they are very different scenarios since you aren't adding those headers in your web app.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure data is updated in DB, your backend is working properly and you are refreshing your react app and still can't see the updated data, then we don't have enough information to solve your issue.

Are you sure you are making the same request from postman and from the react app?
Did you try deleting cache from the browser?

One solution to debug this could be creating a button that calls your `fetchPost` method on click and see what happens

Comment: I'm sure that endpoint and calling code is accurate because if I append `+new Date()` as cache burst then it displays updated content

Comment: Can you please add a console.log of the called endpoint in the ```fethcPost``` method? That will assure  that this is not a problem related to React

Comment: I did and issue is not related to backend

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add `params` or `postSlug` as a `useEffect()` dependency.

Example:

```
const { postSlug } = useParams()

useEffect(() => {

    if(postSlug)
        fetchPost(postSlug)

}, [postSlug])

const fetchPost = (postSlug) => {

    axios
        .get(`https://api.example/v1/json/post?post=${postSlug}`)
        .then((response) => {
            setPost(response.data.data.post);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log({ error }))

}
```

I'm not quite sure if it will work, but without the dependency, perhaps the `fetchPost()` is executing within the `useEffect()` using an empty slug. Hence, the cached response.

Comment: This makes sense, I also believe the endpoint is not the right one maybe because of an empty slug

Comment: @Erik, I tried this also. though slug is included in either case. but doesn't solve the issue itself

Comment: @Mani What is the response if you use a `fetch()` function instead of `axios()`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got web inspector networks' cache disabled.

Make sure that the data you're receiving is exactly what you're accessing:
`response.data.data.post`.data.data doesn't seem well.
Make sure you receive an object and not an array, because you need to map your content if it is an array.

Comment: response.data.data.post displays the old data. plus I don't want to disable cache. that's the whole point :(

Comment: You need to clarify how you "change the backend data" and what the exact flow you wnat to achieve

Comment: it is a simple thing, let say, 1- I change the data directly in db (manual editing) 2- I refresh my ReactJs page then it should reflect changes. right ?

Comment: It should, but if you have cache its normal it doesnt. PHP has cache of its own. Opcache.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php

You might want to disable it for development purposes.

Comment: dear, it is not php issue. because as I mentioned in the question that if I paste the URL in browser or hit the endpoint through postman it shows updated content

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want your backend to inform the front-end that "Hey! My data changed, so, pls, update!" you can use Laravel Broadcasting - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting .
2. Since I do not have a react-app to test your code + typing on mobile, all I can suggest is to try adding the useEffect() dependency and then see if that works.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Post = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  const [post, setPost] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPost();
  }, [post]); <------------- Add the dependency here
...
```

In any case, if Postman processes the API Endpoint properly, then the issue must be with your code.

Comment: it will create an infinite loop but no, it will still not solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

I had one problem like that so i fixed it by adding a useEffect with param that will react as component did update, so once the data get changed in your case the post my state exists will be true then you will be able to render your jsx.

try this :

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const Post = () => {
      const params = useParams();
    
 

     const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
/***************************************/
          const [exists, setExists] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
    post ? setExists(true) : null
       //this exists will let you render your component once the poste state is changed 
      }, [post]);
/****************************************/
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchPost();
      }, []);
    
      const fetchPost = () => {
        axios
          .get(
            `https://api.example/v1/json/post?post=${params.postSlug}`
          )
          .then((response) => {
            setPost(response.data.data.post);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log({ error }));
      };
    
      return exists ? (
        <div className="singlePost">
          <div className="content" key="content">{post.content}</div>
        </div>
      ) : null;
    };
    
    export default Post;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. First, the original problem is not how to display the data, but displaying the *correct* data. Second, the variable `exists` is not needed at all: if you can conditionally update such variable using `post`, then you can conditionally render using the same `post` variable.